# missing parameter type for expanded function (Scala)

Tags: scala

Here's my function:

```scala
def sumOfSquaresOfOdd(in: Seq[Int]): Int = {
  in.filter(_%2==1).map(_*_).reduce(_+_)
}
```

Why am I getting the error "missing parameter type for expanded function"?

Comment: relevant: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/index.html#why-doesnt-my-function-literal-with-_-in-it-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`map`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/collection/IterableOps.html#map%5BB%5D(f:A=%3EB):scala.collection.IterableOnce%5BB%5D) is accepting function with one parameter (`(A) => B`) while every  `_` placeholder represents a separate parameter of [anonymous function](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#placeholder-syntax-for-anonymous-functions) (i.e. `_ * _` is function with two parameters). You can use `i => i * i` lambda for your `map` function:

```scala
def sumOfSquaresOfOdd(in: Seq[Int]): Int = {
  in.filter(_%2==1)
    .map(i => i * i)
    .reduce(_ + _)
}
```

Also you can use `sum` instead of `reduce(_ + _)` (note that `sum` will not throw for empty sequences while `reduce` will):

```scala
def sumOfSquaresOfOdd(in: Seq[Int]): Int = {
  in.filter(_%2==1)
    .map(i => i * i)
    .sum
}
```

Comment: Oh wow I had already tried that earlier and it didn't work, but now I tried it, closed the IDE and opened it again, and it works. Why must programming be this way. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I guess because `map` wants a function of a single argument, and you ask it to call `*` with two arguments.  Replace `_ * _` with `arg => arg * arg` and retry.

Answer (score 2):

"map" was called with a function with two parameters when it is expecting a function of one parameter. There's another small bug due to the use of "reduce" - it throws an exception if there aren't any odd Ints in the input Seq.

A better solution would be:

```
  def sumOfSquaresOfOdd(in: Seq[Int]): Int =
    in.filter(_ % 2 == 1) . map(x => x * x) . sum
```

You must be using Scala2. Scala3 gives a much better error message:

```
Error:
2 |  in.filter(_%2==1).map(_*_).reduce(_+_)
  |                        ^^^
  |                        Wrong number of parameters, expected: 1
```

(Edited to reflect changes in the other answers to this question.)

Comment: Thanks, Patrick. 

Care to also explain the wording of OPs error message; "missing parameter type for expanded function", what tricks Scala into reporting it this way?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any idea.  But see my edits to my original answer.

Comment: or just `sum` instead of `fold` or `reduce`

Comment: Very good point @Guru Stron.  I edited my answer to include your improvement.